# How to initialize 2D array of chars

Tags: c++, arrays

I was trying to write a simple name generator, but I got stuck with array initialization.

1. Why can't I initialize 2D array like this?

   ```
   const char* alphab[2][26] ={{"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"}, 
   {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"}};
   ```

It compiles without errors and warnings, but `cout << alphab[0][5]` prints nothing.

2. Why does this

   ```
   class Sample{
       private:
       char alphnum[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   }
   ```

throw an "initializer-string for array of chars is too long" error, and this

```
char alphnum[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
class Sample{
//code
};
```

doesn't?

Here is my code

```
class NameGen {

private:
    string str;
    char arr[5];
    const char* alphab[2][26] = {{"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"},
        {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"}
    };

public:
    string genName()
    {
        srand(time(0));
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); ++i) {
            arr[i] = *alphab[(i > 0) ? 1 : 0][rand() % 25];
        }
        str = arr;
        return str;
    }
} alph;

int main()
{
    cout << alph.genName() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

No warnings and errors. The output is: Segmentation fault (code dumped)

Comment: Remember that the literal string `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` contains *27* characters, including the terminating `'\0'`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Still not working

Comment: `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` is `alphab[0][0]`. All the other elements of `alphab[0]` are null pointers, and dereferencing them is an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The answer to 1.**

```
const char* alphab[2][26] ={{"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"},
                            {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"}};
```

should be

```
const char* alphab[2] ={{"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"},
                        {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"}};
```

since you don't have an 2-D array of pointer-to-char but just a 1-D array of pointer-to-chars. The line

```
arr[i] = *alphab[(i>0) ? 1: 0][rand() % 25];
```

should then be changed to

```
arr[i] = alphab[(i>0) ? 1: 0][rand() % 25];
```

Live example [here](http://ideone.com/EydC2H).

**The answer to 2.**

Count the number of characters and add an extra one for the `\0` character. You cannot have a zero-sized array as a member variable, so must specify the length, like

```
char alphnum[5] = "test";
```

Comment: 1.Now it works. But it also makes 0 sense to me :\ 
How can it be NOT a 2D array when I'm referencing to it like this: alphab[(i>0) ? 1: 0][rand() % 25].If this is a 1D array, shouldn't it be like: alphab[(i>0) ? 1: 0] ? 
2. I'm curious about why am I able to write nothing in [] when it is defined outside of NameGen class, and not able to do it when it is defined in the class.

Comment: @Pocsss it is a 1D array of *pointers*. When you write `alphab[0]` you get the first pointer that points to the string literal `"ABC..."`, which you then address via `[]` operator (remember that you can access pointer memory using an array-like syntax, instead of writing `*(p+5)` can write `p[5]`). About the second question, I am not sure why the committee decided that, but that's the rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
char alphab[2][27] = { 
    {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"}, 
    {"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"}
};
```

Notice the use of char and char* .
char* can make an array of chars it self!
leave an extra unit for \n.

You can now easily reference the alphab.

```
Cout<< alphab[1][5] ;    //you will get 'F'
```

Comment: you need to put `'` everywhere, like `'a','b'` etc which is a bit painful

Comment: dude ! :D there is no difference !   It could be for example :  char **alpab; then he could initialize the array. or he could define it like char alphab[][] from the beginning !

Comment: Well, then say so, not "try this". This is not a complicated algorithmic question, so syntax matter.

Comment: but it is usable !   i was trying to help, no big deal.  sorry man.

Comment: I will not argue anymore, **it is not usable**. Copy/pasting that line won't compile and that's the end of it.

Comment: Yes, this will now work (have an extra `Y` in the capital letters)